# Restarting an application upon its closing

Tags: windows, script, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to turn some Windows (7, 8, 10) PCs into indie arcade setups for an event. I really want it to be fool proof.

Plugging in controllers and launching a game is easy enough, but games have exit options, and I don't want people exiting the game and rendering the setup useless while waiting for someone with a mouse/keyboard to launch the game again.

I'm a front end web developer so I can code, but I've never done any kind of scripting or automation within Windows, and I'm not entirely sure what all you're capable of (or of all of the available options).

I figure their might be a way to write a script that listens for the closing of an application, and then launches that application again upon it closing. I'm also open to alternate strategies, like firing a script to launch the game when someone hits a home button (but only if there is not an instance of the game already running).

So, I'd appreciate any ideas or input. Again I'm not entirely sure what options there are in Windows for accomplishing this. Accordingly I apologize if my tags are not terribly accurate. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way without requiring anything too complex would be to launch the application with a batch in an infinite loop.

For example, a file called `ReopenNotepad.bat` containing:

```
@echo off
:1
notepad
goto :1
```

This will open up `notepad` and wait for it to be closed. When it *is* closed, it'll loop back to `:1` and open `notepad` again, until the batch cmd prompt window is closed. Obviously amend to the executable of your choosing.

Comment: Love it! Nice and simple. Side question: is there an easy way to hit an executable in a batch file without adding it to PATH? EDIT: Got it, START "path to exe". Cool! Now I just have to figure out why some of these games make the batch open it repeatedly, indefinitely x_x

Comment: @addMitt Eep, don't use `START` with this! It'll call the process asynchronously instead of waiting for one to close. Just use `"full_path_to_exe"`.

Comment: lol whoops! I initially tried that without the quotes and it didn't work, so I Google'd, and my results made it sound like I had to do something special. START seemed appropriate when I found it. Anyhow, this is amazing! Thanks a lot.